# How to create django models Dynamically

Tags: django

My django application need to collect user data(name age country etc) based on his email domain( 'gmail' as in xyz@gmail.com).I wist to create a new table every time i encounter a new email domain.
Can this be done in django ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea.  Your tables would all have the same structure.  All of your data should be stored in a single table, with a `domain` column to keep the data separate.  Why would you want a different table for each domain?  Whatever reason you have, there's a better way to do it.

This idea goes against everything in the design of the relational database, and the Django ORM on top of it.

Comment: So that data of a particular domain can be seperate ! and authentic !

Comment: @user1504247: I'm not sure what "authentic" means.  For "portable", you can extract rows from your table and move the data somewhere else.

Comment: Authentic so that i can give permission to users to manipulate the data of a specific table only !

Comment: @user1504247: In a django app, you typically don't use db-level permissions to protect access to data.  You use a single db user, and the Django app accesses the database using that db user.  Then you implement access controls in the Django app.

Comment: Initially I was thinking of manually setting up new tables using django.db.connection to achieve the same ! But as you suggest this is a 'bad idea'. Are there absolutely no provision of doing this or a better solution(than having a single table !)?

Comment: Having a single table is a fine solution, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Basically i'm a django newbie, and i wanted to keep things simple. Put respective data in respective table. By using a single table i'm bound to screw the 'relational' part of rdbms. Storing all data (name email attachment other user info )in one table will create a management overhead( maybe i'm prejudging)! I'm on it though !